# Getting limited random items from related object in templates?

Tags: python, django

I have an Author model with many books assigned to each one. In my Books model I have: `author = models.ForeignKey(Author)`

In my page, I am listing all the authors I have and under each author I want to display 5 random books.

Is this feasible through the templates only or I must do that in my view? **I mean limiting the results and getting them randomly.**

I'm currently only passing the authors to template, like this: `a = Author.objects.all()`

Please advise.

Comment: Note a good idea if you try to do it in the template. It would violate MVC.

Comment: you should generally make queries through the views and just pass the data to the templates for better performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Do it in your view:

   This query is *"return 5 random books for author `a`"*

   ```
   random_books = Book.objects.filter(author=a).order_by('?')[:5]
   ```
2. Create a [custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) that takes an author and returns random 5 books:

   Create a custom tag:

   ```
   from myapp.models import Book

   def randbooks(author):
       return {'books': Book.objects.filter(author=author).order_by('?')[:5]}

   register.inclusion_tag('book_listing.html')(randbooks)
   ```

   Create a template to show the titles (`book_listing.html`):

   ```
   <ul>
   {% for book in books %}
      <li>{{ book }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```

   Use it in your template like this:

   ```
   {% for author in a %}
     {% randbooks author %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```